# Overwrite chunk cache settings

Tags: r, knitr

I have a `.Rnw` document that relies on sourcing an `R` file which I occasionally change.

I have a lot of chunks that I want to update when I change this source `.R` file, but I don't want
them constantly recalculating as I'm doing regular edits/builds of the `.Rnw` file.

Is there any way to overwrite the `cache=TRUE` chunk option and force the document to recalculate when I change this `.R` file?

Comment: you could erase all (or just the relevant) files in the `cache/` directory

Comment: Seems silly to me that `knitr` only re-evaluates a chunk if the code in the .Rmd (or whatever) changes -- i.e., that `knitr` doesn't check if the _source_ file has changed. My work around is to add some useless whitespace to trick `knitr` into re-evaluating the relevant chunks.